# Bender's height

Tags: linear-algebra

Bender is 2m tall. He uses a machine that creates 2 clones of him self at 60% his height. Then his clones use this machine as well and create 2 more clones each at 60% of their height. If this continues what is the height of each new generation of Benders. If you can i would prefer the equation in y=mX+b format.

Comment: What are you trying to describe? Bender is 2 m tall, each of his immediate copies is 1.2 m tall, and each of their copies is 0.72 m tall. The total height of Bender’s immediate copies is 2.4 m, the total height of their copies is 2.88 m, and the total height of all seven is 7.28 m. That’s about all there is to say, unless you’re asking something about what happens if this process continues indefinitely.

Comment: basically i mean if every knew generation of bender is 60% that of the last one starting at 2m, what is the linear equation for this in y=mX+b format

Comment: Do you want to know what the height of the $n$-th generation copies is in terms of $n$? That’s not a linear function. If we call Bender generation $0$, the height of each copies in generation $n$ is $2(0.6)^n$, and the total height of all $2^n$ copies in generation $n$ is $2(1.2)^n$.

Comment: Let me put it this way: *What do $y$ and $x$ stand for*?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a linear problem, so a linear equation is impossible. Call Bender himself Generation $0$. If $h(n)$ is the height of a copy in Generation $n$, then $$h(n)=2(0.6)^n=2\left(\frac35\right)^n\;,$$ because the height is simply multiplied by $0.6$, or $\frac35$, each generation. Thus, $h(n)$ keeps shrinking, but at a slower and slower rate, getting closer and closer to $0$ but never quite reaching it. Here are the first few generations and the $20$-th:

$$\begin{array}{r|c}
\text{Generation:}&0&1&2&3&4&5&20\\
\text{Height:}&2&1.2&0.72&0.432&0.2592&0.15552&\approx0.000073
\end{array}$$

The number of copies in Generation $n$ is $2^n$, since each generation has twice as many copies as the previous one, so the total height of all members of Generation $n$ is $$2^n\Big(2(0.6)^n\Big)=2(2\cdot0.6)^n=2(1.2)^n=2\left(\frac65\right)^n\;.$$ This number grows, faster and faster. Here are the first few generations and the $20$-th:

$$\begin{array}{r|c}
\text{Generation:}&0&1&2&3&4&5&20\\
\text{Total Height:}&2&2.4&2.88&3.456&4.1472&4.97664&\approx76.6752
\end{array}$$

The total height of all copies in Generations $0$ through $n$ is given by the expression $$10\Big((1.2)^{n+1}-1\Big)\;.$$

Comment: On the other hand the total weight of all these clones (including Bender) is only $1.76$ times Bender's weight!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly then :

$f(0)=h=2 m$

$f(1)=0.6 \cdot h$

$f(2)=0.6 \cdot 0.6 \cdot h$

$\vdots$

$f(n)=(0.6)^n \cdot h=2 \cdot (0.6)^n $

where $f(n)$ is height of nth generation .